# Word Interop Add Document Property Field to Table - "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'This command is not available.' "

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, word-interop

I'm trying to add a field for a custom document property into a table in a Word document using the Word Interop. However, when I do this I'm getting an error:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'This command is not available.'"

I've tried multiple ways to get around this, and the code works for just adding the field to a range within the document, but any time I try to add the field to the cell within the table I'm getting the same error. Does anyone know of a way to do this, or what I'm doing wrong.

Some example code of what I'm trying to do is:

```
Word.Section section = wordDoc.Sections[1];
Word.Range range = section.Range;
Word.Table table = range.Tables.Add(range, 1, 3);
//Format table
table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Fields.Add(table.Cell(1,1).Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDocProperty,
    "DocPropertyName", true);
```

Comment: Does the _version_ of the _Word Interop library_ you are compiling against match the _version of Word_ your program is interacting with at runtime?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using square brackets for `table.Cell(1, 1)` and the like?

Comment: Yes, the version of the interop library is the same. `table.Cell(1, 1)` is correct as table.Cell is a method that returns the cell at the given location, rather than a collection of Cells

Comment: It must be a Word thing.   In Excel, you can do **impossible** things with C# like  `Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1]; sheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Hello world!";    sheet.Range["A1", "J1"].Style = heading3;` but _["provided you’re doing so on a COM type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/july/csharp-4-0-new-csharp-features-in-the-net-framework-4)_.   Notice the `.["A1", "J1"]`.   Check out [Indexed Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/july/csharp-4-0-new-csharp-features-in-the-net-framework-4)

Comment: …on that page you will also see examples of old vs new ways of invoking.

Comment: cell.range refers to the whole cell structure including cell boundary.  I’ve not tested this but I assume that is the problem.  Try this:  Duplicate the cell range in a local variable range and collapse it so it points to the start of the cell text content and then then insert the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as to my earlier comment, it is indeed that you cannot add a field to the cell.range as a whole: below sample insert a page number in a table in the footer 'foot' as "x of y" where x is current page number and y the total number of pages.

```
 Dim rng As Range = footerTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Duplicate
 rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
 
 Dim fld As Field = foot.Range.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=WdFieldType.wdFieldPage)

 If fld.Result.Text <> Nothing Then rng.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=fld.Result.Text.Count)
 
 rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
 rng.InsertAfter(Text:=" of ")
 rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)

 foot.Range.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages)
```

Ps. works with custom property too.